# Can 42 be precisely represented as a floating-point?

Tags: floating-point, double, ieee-754

I have learned that 0.1 cannot be exactly represented as a floating-point number.  The textbook argument was that `0.1` cannot be written as a kind of binary-based scientific notation, although  I have never been certain  how people *prove* that argument. Related to that, my question now is

> Can 42 be precisely represented as a floating-point ?

Say we are discussing the IEEE-754 `binary64` format.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem with the decimal portion is that it can only be approximated using a combination of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32, ... , 1/(2^n), which can't get exactly 0.1. But for integers, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, an integer value small enough to fit floating point's mantissa (`42` in your case) *can* be represented precisely

```
 42 (decimal) == 101010 (binary)
```

on the contary, `1/10` *can't* be represented precisely:

```
 0.1 (decimal) == 0.0001100110011001100... (binary)
```

since `0.1` decimal is a binary *periodical fraction*

Comment: @zell: `42` is small enough (less than 52 bit) to fit `double` mantissa: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format. You *can* represent `0.1` as `1 * 10 ^-1` and represent both `1` and `-1` precisely - it's the idea of `decimal` type